# Qt QMainWindow difference between closing by user and abort via system

Tags: qt, events, abort, qmainwindow

Could you tell me how can I determine between QMainWindow close event initiated by user and abonormal termination by SIG_KILL in Linux or TerminateProcess() in Windows?
That's because the difference in urgency exists.
I can refuse closing by user or user can think as long as required.
But I have to save intermediate results and current state as soon as possible when aborting or till the user will do next fatal abort try.
I can try to figure out analysing the mouse position on closeEvent(). But it depends on the taskbar look. I can set the app to non-minimized state and wait the next user actions. But that's not a good behaviour in the abort case. User can try the next fatal abort actions or the time for save would lost.
Best regards, Gennady

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question please.

Answer (score 2):

If you application receives a `SIGKILL`, it *will not* have any time to do anything. It is terminated on the spot. You can't catch or block that signal. So you can't "differentiate" a SIGKILL from normal application shutdown: you will not know when you have been forcefully killed. (Same thing for `TerminateProcess()`.)

If you need to do something during normal application shutdown, you should connect your cleanup routine to the [`QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal. Check the docs, that is exactly what it is designed for.